# why (num) from type list in my code take one value and if I add new value is replace old value ? because of this I can't get average

Tags: python

I write code takes from user some numbers and get summation and average , my problem it is I can't add more than one value in my list (num) , it is just replace old value by new value

```
class game_2_sum():
    print('welcome')
    print('please enter number you want sum it , press x if you finish')
    z=0
    num=[]
    while True:
        try:
            inp=input()
            if inp.__eq__('x'):
                break
            else:
                num=[float(inp)]
            for x in num:
                z+=int(x)
        except ValueError:
            print('please enter right number ')
    print('total is {}'.format(z))
    print('average is {}'.format(z/len(num)))
    print(num)
```

> I expect the output of summation (1,2,3) is 6 and average is 2.0
>
> but the actual output is average 6.0

Comment: Use num.append(float(inp))

Comment: You probably meant `num.append(float(inp))`. You're currently replacing `num` by a new list containing only your last input.

Comment: thank you it is work it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is write answer , thank you to how is help me ❤

```
class game_2_sum():
    print('welcome')
    print('please enter number you want sum it , press x if you finish')
    z=0
    num=[]
    while True:
        try:
            inp=input()
            if inp.__eq__('x'):
                break
            else:
                num.append(float(inp))
        except ValueError:
            print('please enter right number ')
    for x in num:
        z+=int(x)
    print('total is {}'.format(z))
    print('average is {}'.format(z/len(num)))
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

the num is overwritten, thus the len of it is the last input

```
class game_2_sum():
    print('welcome')
    print('please enter number you want sum it , press x if you finish')
    z=l=0
    num=[]
    while True:
        try:
            inp=input()
            if inp.__eq__('x'):
                break
            else:
                num=[float(inp)]
            for x in num:
                z+=int(x)
                l+=1

        except ValueError:
            print('please enter right number ')
    print('total is {}'.format(z))
    print('average is {}'.format(z/l))
    print(num)
```